# Angular8 - sending the model as post request with separate fields

Tags: javascript, angular, post

I have the following interface. It's connected with fields of my form in view. It's ok and works:

```
export interface User {
    name: string;
    surname: string
}
```

When the form is submitted, the following function is calling:

```
  onSubmit(myuser: User){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiBaseUrl + '/Users/', myuser
      { 
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      }
    );
  }
```

Everything is fine, but my param value (`myuser`) is equal to:

```
{name: "MyName", surname: "MySurname" }
```

Unfortunately, the api that I use reject this format of paramters. Each param must be sent individually as a separeted field. For example, the below solution works perfectly and it's valid of my api.

```
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params.append("name", "myName");
  params.append("surname", "mySurname");

  onSubmit(myuser: User){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiBaseUrl + '/Users/', params
      { 
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      }
    );
  }
```

Although I found solution for me, I think that it's very ugly code. It'll be a huge problem for bigger models. In this way, I decided to improve my function. I wanted to auto-conversion from my `myUser` object to a map. So I tried:

```
Object.keys(myUser).forEach(function (key) {
   params = params.append(key, dataJson[key]);
});
```

Unfortunately, the code above works surprisingly for me. The result is a following map:

```
map: Map(2)
[[Entries]]
0: {"name" => Array(1)}
1: {"surname" => Array(1)}
```

Each key has array (with one element) as a value. It's a trap. I would like to have a map whose elements look like: `{ "key" => "stringValue" }`. When any value is an array, api rejects my request.  I understand how the code works. This allow security because there can be more than one element  in an array with the same (future) key. In my case, this will never be the case - the names are unique. Therefore, I would like my map not to use arrays as a value.

I spent a lot of time on it and I have no more ideas.
I would like to solve it in a simple and universal way.

Thanks!

Comment: What is dataJson and where does it come from?
Shouldn't you access your myUser object in order to get the attribute data?
-> myUser[key]

Comment: Why not call JSON.stringify with your myuser argument? Most APIs accept JSON formatted data.